# Traefik v2.2 on Digital Ocean Kubernetes, wildcard domain certificate works, but not with port number

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt, traefik, traefik-ingress

I am adding Traefik support for our Digital Ocean Kubernetes cluster, have used dnsChallenge to successfully get a wildcard SSL domain certificate from LetsEncrypt.

When I try to access sites with the same domain name, everything works well:

```
$ curl -v https://user.example.io
*   Trying 159.203.52.215:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to user.example.io (159.203.52.215) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /home/user/anaconda3/ssl/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=example.io
*  start date: Oct 23 15:49:19 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 21 15:49:19 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "user.example.io" matched cert's "user.example.io"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: user.example.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< content-length: 40
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< date: Sun, 25 Oct 2020 03:07:06 GMT
< etag: W/"28-v4XAuYZPRDT3aiocGxlWbac4/oE"
< vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-powered-by: Express
< 
* Connection #0 to host user.example.io left intact
{"message":"User microservice"}
```

However, if it's sites with port number, like the Traefik dashboard, this will not work:

```
$ curl -v https://traefik.example.io:8080
*   Trying 159.203.52.215:8080...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to traefik.example.io (159.203.52.215) port 8080 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /home/user/anaconda3/ssl/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

If it is without the port number 8080, the wildcard domain certificate will be used, but of course I will get a "404 Not Found"..

```
$ curl -v https://traefik.example.io
*   Trying 159.203.52.215:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to traefik.example.io (159.203.52.215) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /home/user/anaconda3/ssl/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=example.io
*  start date: Oct 23 15:49:19 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 21 15:49:19 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "traefik.example.io" matched cert's "traefik.example.io"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: traefik.example.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< date: Sun, 25 Oct 2020 03:18:38 GMT
< content-length: 19
< 
404 page not found
* Connection #0 to host traefik.example.io left intact
```

BTW, the Traefik dashboard can be successfully accessed using http.

The following is my IngressRoute setting, I guess there must be some problems here:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: ingressroutetls
  namespace: ingress-traefik
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure

  routes:
  - match: Host(`example.io`) && Path('/')
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: example-com
      port: 443

  - match: Host(`traefik.example.io`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: traefik-example-com
      port: 8080

  tls:
    cetResolver: mlResolver
    domains:
    - main: example.io
      sans:
      - '*.example.io'
```

Can anyone find out what the problem might be?

**** IngressRoute changed after @Jakub's advice (but still no luck) ****

```
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: ingressroutetls
  namespace: ingress-traefik
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure

  routes:
  - match: Host(`traefik.example.io`) && (PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard`))
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: api@internal
      kind: TraefikService

  - match: Host(`example.io`) && Path('/')
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: example.io
      port: 443

  tls:
    cetResolver: mlResolver
    domains:
    - main: example.io
      sans:
      - '*.example.io'
```

I have tried to curl both `https://traefik.example.io/dashboard`, `https://traefik.example.io/api` and `https://traefik.example.io`, all having the same results as before. (I had also tried to create a separate IngressRoute for dashboard, but the result did not change)

```
$ curl -v https://traefik.example.io/dashboard
*   Trying 159.203.52.215:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to traefik.example.io (159.203.52.215) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /home/user/anaconda3/ssl/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=example.io
*  start date: Oct 23 15:49:19 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 21 15:49:19 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "traefik.example.io" matched cert's "traefik.example.io"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1
> Host: traefik.example.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< date: Mon, 26 Oct 2020 15:44:12 GMT
< content-length: 19
< 
404 page not found
* Connection #0 to host traefik.example.io left intact
```

Comment: AFAIK you should create another route for your `/dashboard` prefix and use it instead of the port. So as mentioned in [documentation](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/operations/dashboard/#dashboard-router-rule) could you try to add the `/dashboard` prefix? There is an example for kubernetes if you expand the `Dashboard Dynamic Configuration Examples` list. Let me know if that answer your question.

Comment: Thanks @Jakub. I have tried the example but still no luck. The following is my modified ingressRoute file:

---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: dashboardingressroute
  namespace: ingress-traefik
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure

  routes:
  - match: Host(`traefik.example.com`) && (PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard`))
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: api@internal
      kind: TraefikService

Comment: Hi @Jakub, BTW, I have updated my modifications on the Question accordingly.

Comment: I just ran into exactly the same error. Did you ever find a solution here?

Comment: @kaiser, I solved the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64709491/6716204